# "Python Object search" I want to speed up the search for an object

Tags: python, pyautogui

Function

```
def SearchFloat(self):
        image = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(self.Pathadasaew,region=(self.fishBar["left"],self.fishBar["top"],self.fishBar["width"],self.fishBar["height"]),confidence=0.2)
        if image == None:
           return int(image[0] - 839)
```

Function

```
def GameFloat(self):
    while self.CheckFishBar():
          print("GO")
          Pixel = self.SearchFloat()
          print("tt=",Pixel)
          self.Start(Pixel)
```

How to optimize your code to make it search fast

The object we are looking for
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZtvS.png

I want to speed up the search for an object

Comment: there's no way which can speed up any method. The locateonscreen method always is too slow.

Comment: Maybe there are other ways then?